# Use two nested dispatch_async in parallel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

Could someone explain to me why I get second NSLog(images count) BEFORE first NSLog(text count) in debug console?

My purpose of having two parallel `dispatch_async` (each one is nested) is to separately download text and image into a table view using core data. Note that image data are much bigger than text.

I firstly try downloading both text and images in one nested`dispatch_async` (jump back to main queue to do mapping and commit of both text and images of course). However, I notice significant delay in displaying cells on screen. I figure there must be some better ways to do it. Any suggestion is appreciate.

```
-(void)doSometing
{   
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0),^{
        // download text data
        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{  
            NSLog(@"Text count is %d \n\n",[text count]);
            // insert text data to context
            // commit text data
        }];
    });


    // see if I can shorten wait time by download image separately
    //
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
        // download image

        [document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"Images count is %d \n\n",[images count]);
            // insert images into context
            // commit images     
        }];
    });

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "nested dispatch_async"? I see only 2 (concurrent) dispatch_async calls. - You could add NSLog() statements before and after "download text data" and before and after "download image" to check if the second task is faster than the first (even if you expect the first one to be faster).

Comment: Sorry for the confusing. Since `performBlock` runs on main queue in this case, it's just like typical nested async calls, isn't it?

Comment: Now I understand what you mean. The (inner) blocks for the main context are executed sequentially on the main thread. The first block enqueued with `performBlock` should execute first.

Comment: Why are you using performBlock?  This seems counter-intuitive given what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jkh,`performBlcok` seems like the recommended way by Apple for dealing with nested contexts. And I am using UIManagedDocument which have nested contexts by default